# jstack - Dont contains the thread stack trace

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

While using the jstack to know about the threads for the particular process. For numerous Threads, I can't find any stack trace.

```
"Thread-4978" #5139 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d451800 nid=0x8530 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-4808" #4969 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d44f000 nid=0x8eb0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Other than the runnable state I can't get any information from it. Please guide me to debug the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Java thread has no Java stack trace, when

- The thread is about to start, and is running pre-start initialization or JVM TI [`ThreadStart`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#ThreadStart) handler.
- The thread is about to terminate, and is running post-exit cleanup or JVM TI [`ThreadEnd`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#ThreadEnd) handler.
- The thread is a JVM TI [agent thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#RunAgentThread), which is running native code.

To find out what these threads are doing, it's not enough to get Java stack trace - you'd need to get native stack traces as well.

On JDK 8 run

```
jstack -m <pid>
```

On JDK 11 and later

```
jhsdb jstack --mixed --pid <pid>
```

Another option is to use a profiler which is aware of native stacks, e.g. [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/)

When used in threaded mode (`-t`), async-profiler can show mixed stack traces of all threads in the JVM, even if they have no Java stack trace.

For example, when I debugged a similar issue, async-profiler showed me the following stack trace:

[image: native-stack]

In my case, this was a JDWP agent running post-thread-end hook. Note that the standard Java debug agent (libjdwp) is a particular case of a JVM TI agent, which has non-trivial `ThreadEnd` handler.

This was a bug [JDK-8227269](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8227269) that resulted in slow termination of threads. So, if you experience problems with debug agent turned on, the first recommendation is to run JVM without JDWP.

Comment: Thanks much for your response. When I am trying jstack -m <pid> getting following errors. 

Exception:
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Windbg Error: GetThreadIdBySystemId
failed!
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.getThreadIdFromSy
sId0(Native Method)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.getThreadIdFromSy
sId(WindbgDebuggerLocal.java:284)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.amd64.WindbgAMD64Thread.getThreadID(W
indbgAMD64Thread.java:88)
        
is there any idea on this?

Comment: @manovenkatesh Ah, you're on Windows. Visual Studio debugger can get stack traces then. But do you run JVM with jdwp or with other `-agentpath` option?

Comment: Thanks much @apangin yes I am in Windows, I will check with visual studio debugger. I am using the JDWP option to run JVM. I added it(after you reminded initially I haven't added it so I got an above-given error) and now I got some native traces, But I got some errors too. 
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Windbg Error: ReadVirtual failed! - I am not sure about this error. sorry to ask too much of exception related queries. But I don't get anything useful on the internet when I searched about it. Once again thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try "-l" and "-e" option, it could provide more information on the other hand, also you can get the information via java code.

```
jstack -l -e 18632

Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```